# add a counter to lapply(do.call) - R

Tags: r, counter, lapply, rbind, do.call

I have a file which includes many folders. I wrote the following code to get the address of all files, import them into R and bind them that works well. The problem is, some of the file has different number of columns, which resulted in showing an error. My question is how can add a counter to the third line of my code? I basically want to check when my counter stops, and then I manually drop that file that has different number of columns from others. 
Thanks

```
file_names <- list.files(path="D:/ABCDE", recursive=TRUE)
setwd("D:/ ABCDE ") 
all_dta <- do.call(rbind, lapply(file_names, function(x) read.csv(file=x,header = FALSE)))
```

Comment: You can use `data.table::rbind` with `fill = TRUE` to  fill missing columns with NAs

Answer (score 0):

To add a counter to `lapply` I would just do:

```
file_names <- list.files(path="D:/ABCDE", recursive=TRUE)
idx=1:length(filenames) #this will server as your 'counter'
lapply(idx, function(i) {print(file_names[i]); read.csv(file=file_names[i],header = FALSE)}) # this will print the file and when the loop stops you'll see the file that is faulty
```

However as another solution- both to know which files are faulty and skip them naturally- I would do:

```
wanted=c()
for(f in file_names){
    first_line=system(paste0('head -n 1',f),intern=T) # sends prompt to command line to print first line of files. intern=T means one can set this to a variable
if(nchar(first_line > quota)){ #set quota to provide threshold for a number of columns
     wanted=c(wanted,f)
}
}
```

You could also do the above with `sapply`.

And then:

```
all_dta <- do.call(rbind, lapply(wanted, function(x) read.csv(file=x,header = FALSE)))
```

And if you want to know which files are faulty (i.e. which ones don't contain enough columns). Just find the files that have less than the quota number of columns:

```
unwanted=c()
for(f in file_names){
    first_line=system(paste0('head -n 1',f),intern=T) # sends prompt to command line to print first line of files. intern=T means one can set this to a variable
if(nchar(first_line < quota)){ 
     unwanted=c(unwanted,f)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution is to modify the call to skip the first row and just take all of the files with dplyr::bind_rows()

```
file_names <- list.files(path="D:/ABCDE", recursive=TRUE)
setwd("D:/ ABCDE ") 
all_dta <- do.call(dplyr::bind_rows, lapply(file_names, function(x) read.table(file=x,header = FALSE, sep = ',', skip = 1)))
```

The only thing is that you'd need to set the column names. You could either read one row to get the names or manually do it if there aren't a lot of columns.